# Remove a leaf from a BinaryTree

Tags: java, binary-tree

My code below will remove a tree with two children, or one child. But a leaf (a tree with zero children) I can't seem to crack. My `BSTNode<E>` also contains a `.parent` which identifies it's parent. I'm not sure if that would help with this implementation or not.

```
@Override
public E delete(E target) {
    return delete(this.root, target);
}

private E delete(BSTNode<E> localRoot, E target) {
    // ... Trying to delete an item that's not in the tree?
    if (localRoot == null) {
        return null;
    }

    int compareResult = c.compare(target, localRoot.data);

    // Traverse the tree...
    if (compareResult < 0) {
        return delete(localRoot.left, target);
    } else if (compareResult > 0) {
        return delete(localRoot.right, target);
    } else {
        // Found the item! Oh boy here we go!
        E retVal = localRoot.data;

        /*
         * Both left and right exist under the targeted node.
         * Find the largest child under the right side of the node.
         * Set the largest data to the 'deleted' node, then delete that node.
         */
        if (localRoot.left != null && localRoot.right != null) {
            /*
             * Two children, find the smallest and assign it.
             */
            localRoot.data = localRoot.right.data;
            localRoot.right = findLargestChild(localRoot.right);
        } else if (localRoot.left != null) {
            localRoot.data = localRoot.left.data;
            localRoot.left = findSmallestChild(localRoot.left);
        } else if (localRoot.right != null) {
            localRoot.data = localRoot.right.data;
            localRoot.right = findLargestChild(localRoot.right);
        } else {
            /*
             * TODO:
             * Remove a leaf.
             */
            System.out.println("Removing leaf..." + localRoot.data.toString());
            localRoot = null;
        }

        return retVal;
    }
}
```

Comment: "My code below will remove a tree with two children, or one child."
Remove from what? You want to remove a sub-tree from a tree?

Comment: Yeah, well each tree is a node consisting of a data value, and two children (left and right). These children are either trees or null. The code i have thus far will remove a tree which has two children (trees that are not null) or one child. However, a tree with no children (both left and right are null) doesn't work. That's where my TODO commend resides.

Comment: In the case of a leaf, you just want to remove it, so simply set its parent's child to `null`. This way, from the inside of your tree, there's no mean to access the leaf, so it's basically not in the tree anymore. Isn't that the behaviour you expect?

Comment: That's correct. However, simply doing `localRoot = null` doesn't work. I think this is because localRoot is just a reference to the tree.

Comment: Of course, `localRoot = null` means "you have no parent anymore", but you access a tree's elements from the root. So you must tell its parent that it has no child anymore, like `localRoot.right = null`. This way, when exploring the tree from the root, you will find no path to the deleted leaf.

Answer (score 0):

Using `localRoot.parent` I was able to delete (`null`) the child of the `localRoot`'s parent. This feels backwards, but it's passing JUnit Tests...

```
private E delete(BSTNode<E> localRoot, E target) {
    // ... Trying to delete an item that's not in the tree?
    if (localRoot == null) {
        return null;
    }

    int compareResult = c.compare(target, localRoot.data);

    // Traverse the tree...
    if (compareResult < 0) {
        return delete(localRoot.left, target);
    } else if (compareResult > 0) {
        return delete(localRoot.right, target);
    } else {
        // Found the item! Oh boy here we go!
        E retVal = localRoot.data;

        if (localRoot.right != null) {
            /*
             * Assign the largest value to the tree.
             */
            localRoot.data = localRoot.right.data;
            localRoot.right = findLargestChild(localRoot.right);
        } else if (localRoot.left != null) {
            /*
             * Since the largest value didn't exist, assign the smallest.
             */
            localRoot.data = localRoot.left.data;
            localRoot.left = findSmallestChild(localRoot.left);
        } else {
            /*
             * Remove a leaf.
             */
            System.out.println("Removing leaf or left..." + localRoot.data.toString());
            if (c.compare(target, localRoot.parent.left.data) == 0) {
                localRoot.parent.left = null;
            } else {
                localRoot.parent.right = null;
            }
        }

        return retVal;
    }
}
```